Is it possible to point dynamic expression after AS operator in Kotlin
I have a problem: kotlin let us make statements like this:
val castedObject = otherObject as CastedObjectClass

and we always hardcode this CastedObjectClass, in other words, statement after the as operator is always static. I want to have a dynamic class name after as, like this:
val castedObject = otherObject as "StringRepresentingSomeClassNameAtClasspath"

"StringRepresentingSomeClassNameAtClasspath" should be resolved at runtime. Is it possible to do so in Kotlin?
I tried to use kotlin.reflect.cast but that didn't work.

it doesnt help because we need to specify static generic in that solution
